# DirectLineJS Client Library

Tags: javascript, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am trying to use DirectLineJS library in my Web App (HTML5 and Javascript).

I followed the instruction from the following site.

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS

Are these instruction applied to Html/Javascript project too. Or, they are the instruction related to nodejs.

Actually I used following unpkg CDN file as written in the instruction.

**>> Use the unpkg CDN, e.g. `<script src="http://unpkg.com/botframework-directlinejs/directLine.js"/>`** 
But i stuck on how to proceed with this file creating object, starting conversation. I tried to look into the file content too. But looks pretty difficult to understand.

Can anybody share any hint or code snippet on how to utilize above library.

Comment: Have you checked out these samples: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-DirectLine

Answer (score 3):

The namespace has changed. Now you can use DirectLine like this:

```
var directLine = new DirectLine.DirectLine({
                        secret: this.secret,
                        webSocket: false,
                        pollingInterval: 1000
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The samples/instructions in the site are using `TypeScript`, however most of the code can be used in HTML (you only need to remove the `import { DirectLine } from 'botframework-directlinejs';`

For example, you can use the following code to create the object:

```
var directLine = new DirectLine({
    secret: /* put your Direct Line secret here */,
    token: /* or put your Direct Line token here (supply secret OR token, not both) */,
    domain: /* optional: if you are not using the default Direct Line endpoint, e.g. if you are using a region-specific endpoint, put its full URL here */
    webSocket: /* optional: false if you want to use polling GET to receive messages. Defaults to true (use WebSocket). */,
    pollingInterval: /* optional: set polling interval in milliseconds. Default to 1000 */,
});
```

Comment: @Ejadib I finally decided to use, TypeScript and React. I am able to refer the botframework-directlinejs module. But when I try to compile my typescript file it ends up with the following error <<**.../node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(69,60): error TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.**>